# How to solve issue in permission check in marshamallow or above?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am working on application in which I want to check permissions for marshmallow and above. I have used permission code in Splash screen. Now what i want that when I launch application the first splash screen appear for 5 seconds and then redirect to home activity and also check for permission. Now I am facing problem that only spash screen in showing continuously and nothing happen. How can I solve this problem ?

permissions in Manifest file-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.secure.cod.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Activity-

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    private static final int PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT = 100;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING = 101;
    String[] permissionsRequired = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
    private SharedPreferences permissionStatus;
    private boolean sentToSettings = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        permissionStatus = getSharedPreferences("permissionStatus",MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT){
            //check if all permissions are granted
            boolean allgranted = false;
            for(int i=0;i<grantResults.length;i++){
                if(grantResults[i]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    allgranted = true;
                } else {
                    allgranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(allgranted){
                proceedAfterPermission();
            } else if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[0])
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[1])
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[2])
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[3])
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[4])
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[5])
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[6])
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[7])){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera and Location permissions.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired,PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Unable to get Permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Got Permission
                proceedAfterPermission();
            }else {
                getPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private void proceedAfterPermission() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We got All Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        if (sentToSettings) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Got Permission
                proceedAfterPermission();
            }else {
                getPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    public void getPermission(){
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[3]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[4]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[5]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[6]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[7]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired[0])
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[3]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[4]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[5]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[6]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[7]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //Show Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera and Location permissions.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired,PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(permissionsRequired[0],false)) {
                //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Multiple Permissions");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs Camera and Location permissions.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        sentToSettings = true;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant  Camera and Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }  else {
                //just request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,permissionsRequired,PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
            }


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(permissionsRequired[0],true);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for permission check never runs. I see that you probably want to start it in the onPostResume method, but the sentToSettings variable is initialized with false and therefore the permission check never runs.

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    if (sentToSettings) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, permissionsRequired[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Got Permission
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }else {
            getPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PrefM pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle args) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(args);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        pref = new PrefM(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        init();


    }

    private void init() {
        if (!pref.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        } else {
            metho();

        }
    }

    private void metho() {
        pref.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 3000); // 3sec


    }

    public static class PrefM {

        private SharedPreferences pref;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        private Context _context;
        private int MODE = 0;

        public PrefM(Context context) {
            this._context = context;
            pref = _context.getSharedPreferences("First_Time", MODE);
            editor = pref.edit();
        }

        public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
            editor.putBoolean("first_time", isFirstTime);
            editor.commit();
        }

        public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
            return pref.getBoolean("first_time", true);
        }

    }
```

**HomeActivity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        perm();

        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        init();


    }

    private void init() {

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }

    //onBackPressed method
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed: ");
        HomeActivity.this.finish();

    }


    //Permission method.
    private void perm() {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int hasStoragePermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int hasStorage = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int hasAccessPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            int hasInternetPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
            int hasNetworkPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
            int hasWifiPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);


            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

            if (hasWifiPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
            }

            if (hasNetworkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
            }

            if (hasInternetPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
            }


            if (hasStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

            if (hasStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            if (hasAccessPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }

            if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
                requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), PERMISSION);
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION:
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied: " + permissions[i] + ". This may cause " +
                                "the app to behave abnormally", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```